# Unable to install grub bootloader of kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, grub, uefi, window

I have windows 10 installed on my laptop and need to dual boot it with kali linux.

I tried to install Kali Linux using a bootable usb. 
I installed the system successfully but the got an error while installing grub.

```
Error: unable to install grub in dummy
```

I searched over internet and tried installing using a Kali live usb.

I used the following commands in terminal:

```
fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Then I got errors.

efi variables are not supported on this system.
efi variables are not supported on this system.

grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory.

But i have efi partition at sda1.

I rechecked this on internet and used this command:

```
sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt/efi
```

And then got the error:

```
failed to get canonical path of /mnt/efi
```

What should I do?

I have an HP ay512tx laptop and have 8 GB of RAM

[image]

Comment: see https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?35926-Executing-grub-install-dummy-failed

Comment: https://techlog360.com/how-to-dual-boot-kali-linux-v2-0-with-windows-10/

Comment: Please enter the errors into the text of your question.

Comment: This works: [UEFI-How-to-repair-kali-linux-grub-dual-boot-with-Windows-10](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?36601-UEFI-How-to-repair-kali-linux-grub-dual-boot-with-Windows-10)